# What is the best practice to secure your facebook chatbot webhook?

Tags: webhooks, facebook-chatbot

I am playing around with developing a chatbot on facebook messenger platform. I went through the Facebook document and couldn't find how to protect my `webhook` from random calls.

For example, if users can buy stuff with my bots, an attacker that knows someone's userId can start placing unauthorized orders by making calls to my webhook.

I have several ideas on how to protect this.

> 1. Whitelist my API to only calls from Facebook.
> 2. Create something
>    like CSRF tokens with the postback calls.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, how did you even access the Messenger apps setting page? It just opens up blank page for me when I click on the Messenger tab on an app settings page.

Comment: I don't remember how I did it exactly but i believe it shows you blank if you haven't setup the webhook and selected messages. Try following this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart)

Comment: I was following that only. In point #2:Setup Webhook, it says: "click on the "Messenger" product you just added". I'm not able to add the product in the first place.

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem. Although I created a webhook the Messenger page is still empty. I use the old dashboard and not the new one that is mentioned in the guide.

Answer (score 9):

Facebook has of course already implemented a mechanism by which you can check if requests made to your callback URL are genuine (everything else would just be negligence on their part) – see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#validate-payloads

> We sign all Event Notification payloads with a **SHA256** signature and include the signature in the request's `X-Hub-Signature-256` header, preceded with `sha256=`. You don't have to validate the payload, but you should.
>
> To validate the payload:
>
> 1. Generate a **SHA256** signature using the payload and your app's **App Secret**.
> 2. Compare your signature to the signature in the `X-Hub-Signature-256` header (everything after `sha256=`). If the signatures match, the payload is genuine.
>
> Please note that we generate the signature using an *escaped unicode* version of the payload, with lowercase hex digits. If you just calculate against the decoded bytes, you will end up with a different signature. For example, the string `äöå` should be escaped to `\u00e4\u00f6\u00e5`.

Comment: Cool! I will look into this. Thanks!

Comment: @nate Did you find out a way to do this? I'm having trouble getting my signature to match what Facebook is sending.

Comment: @CBroe is the X-Hub-Signature not only sent with GET requests? Looking at Heroku and Parse's code (in the examples), it seems the POST requests are left unverified. How does this stop someone from posing to be a user, as nate asked?

Comment: @forallepsilon: No, it should work the same way for POST requests. Updates are always send via POST, so it would make no sense to leave out the verification/signature in this case.

Comment: @CBroe I figured this was the case but cannot seem to find the signature being sent with post requests. Can you give me a small code sample of how to verify it? Much appreciated.

Comment: Well if you can't even "find" the signature, then what do you want to verify ....? Suggest you make a debug output of all the HTTP request headers first, and check what you really got in there.

Comment: @CBroe As an example, https://github.com/fbsamples/graph-api-webhooks-samples/blob/master/heroku/index.js only verifies on GET requests. Should it not be done on POST as well?

Comment: I don’t see any validation in that script at all. But anyway, yes, you should validate it on the incoming POST requests as well, if you want to be sure the data is genuine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to CBroe's answer, the snippet below represents signature verification implementation as NestJS guard.

```js
// src/common/guards/signature-verification.guard.ts
@Injectable()
export class SignatureVerificationGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const {
      rawBody,
      headers: { 'x-hub-signature': signature },
    } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const { sha1 } = parse(signature);
    if (!sha1) return false;

    const appSecret = this.configService.get('MESSENGER_APP_SECRET');
    const digest = createHmac('sha1', appSecret).update(rawBody).digest('hex');
    const hashBufferFromBody = Buffer.from(`sha1=${digest}`, 'utf-8');
    const bufferFromSignature = Buffer.from(signature, 'utf-8');

    if (hashBufferFromBody.length !== bufferFromSignature.length)
      return false;

    return timingSafeEqual(hashBufferFromBody, bufferFromSignature);
  }
}
```

```js
// src/modules/webhook/webhook.controller.ts
@UseGuards(SignatureVerificationGuard)
@Post()
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
handleWebhook(@Body() data) {
  // ...
}
```